# How Can I Create Bullet In 2D Libgdx Game

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, 2d

I create a 2D Libgdx game. The game look like Flappy Bird but I want to add bullet I searched about 1 week but I did not find anything .

Actually I found but they were complicated I think. I do not want to auto shot. User have only 3 bullets and fire them.

How can I create bullets in my game class .If there is simple way to create them can anyone tell me .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRdP.png)

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather abstract without any code snippets, but my suggestion would be an object-oriented approach.

1. Create a Bullet class to store the properties of your bullet. (e.g. speed, position)
2. In your player class, create an array of your Bullet objects.
3. Set up event listener for when your user hits the 'shoot' button. When they do add a bullet to your array. Starting position will be next to that of your player's.
4. When the bullet makes contact, or leaves the screen, remove it from your array. (careful with this part ;)).

Sorry my answer isn't very detailed, but without code that's all I can give. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your help.I want to add something about bullets .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.I want to add something about bullets .I want to touch the button which I created in my game when I touch the button bullet should fire how can ı do this  actually ı did but it did not draw my bullet here is my codes

```
Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.setDebug(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));
    final TextButton atis = new TextButton("", skin);
    table.row().pad(10, 0, 10, 0);//UÇAK1 BOTUNUN YERİ
    table.add(atis).uniformX();
    atis.addListener( new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            stage= new Stage();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw( bulletTexture, birdX+testBullet.bulletLocation.x, birdY );
            batch.end();
        };
    });
```